# Electron Notification not working on macOS (bonus mdn speech api)

Tags: javascript, push-notification, electron, voice-recognition, html5-notifications

I am trying to create notifications on macOs using the electron framework. I have cloned the open source Quickstart from GitHub and the only code in my renderer.js process is below:

```
        var myNotification = new Notification('Electron Notification', {
            'body':"test"
        })
```

No notifications. No errors. Nothing. Please help! I have tried:

```
            body:"test"
        })
```

Ps. I am also trying to use the mdn voice recognition api, which is working perfectly when I launch in browser but is not working at all in electron. Why could this be.
Many thanks

Comment: `Notification` is a main process module. If you want to use Notifications on the renderer, look at the [HTML5 Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) which, although almost identical, requires permission to be used.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to check your system preferences, go to System Preferences -> Notifications -> electron, there's a switch that says "Allow Notifications from Electron" and if it's off just turn it on and you should be able to send the desktop notification.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your Mac is not in "**Do Not Disturb**" mode, look for a  (moon) icon, and disable "**Do Not Disturb**".

It took me a while to figure that out.

Comment: Can't believe this was it — thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure to check the top level notification settings in System Preferences > Notifications.

In my case, I was mirroring my development computer's screen and I had to switch on the option **"Allow notifications when mirroring or sharing the display**.